# I want to declined a regularization

Tags: contracts, philippines

Hi I am from the Philippines and I want to decline my regularization. I want to move on from them but I could not resign because my contract says if I will resign I should pay them for breaking the contract. I believe this is called security bond but the contract did not say that I could not declined a regularization. Please help is this okay and I dont have the money to pay for the contract and I want to move on from them because they did not keep their promise on making my day off on Saturday. I just want to finish my MBA but I feel that they dont want me to improve. Ask me anything on my contract and I will give it to you.

Comment: You need to talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Pay them what? A bond is something they're holding and withhold from you, not something you pay later. If you haven't done your regularization doesn't that mean you're still in your probation period?

Comment: I need to pay them twice my salary it is stated in the contract and it is called break penalty that is why I am planning not to be regularized to find a better company because this is like a slave contract. I did not asked my employer about that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a brief look into Philippine law, there are situations where regularization is almost mandatory, and others where it is not.

They may not need to explicitly state in the contract that you can be denied regularization. If they didn't keep their promise to making your day off Saturday, that is not good, but unless there is something in writing, I don't think that promise means much.

There may be limits to how much security bond they can ask for.

I think your next steps are to contact the Department of Labor and Employment (DOLE). https://www.dole.gov.ph/24-7-hotline

You should try to include the key information. They may be willing to speak with your employer, or they may be able to give you more specific information.